# What should be 3x images of 100*100 size imageview or button

Tags: ios

For example, I have a 100*100 size imageview or button,and I want to set its image or backgroundImage with a local png file. Based on my understanding, I need to create 3 sets of images, i.e. 100*100 for @1x, 200*200 for @2x, 300*300 for @3x. I am not sure if my understanding is correct or not, can anyone help?

Comment: Yep, you are correct

Comment: the multiplier is a multiplier...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049544/what-should-image-sizes-be-at-1x-2x-and-3x-in-xcode

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 3x is 300*300 in your case...

This [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) shows icon sizes for all.