# What devices uses @1x, @2x and @3x?

Tags: ios

I am curious what iOS devices uses @1x (I know this should be empty), @2x and @3x. When I search on here, I get uncompleted answers like: [What should image sizes be at @1x, @2x and @3x in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049544/what-should-image-sizes-be-at-1x-2x-and-3x-in-xcode) Here I do not see the iPhone 7 or every iPad resolutions. I need to know this because my app requires image **downloads** and I need to know what size that image needs to be, depending on the screensize. I download it from my server and I would like to know what format (1x 2x or 3x) I should use.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `UIScreen.main.scale` for each of the devices to figure out if it is @1x, @2x, or @3x. If you are requesting specific image sizes in code, then specify your size in code in @1x and multiply the width and height by `UIScreen.main.scale`.

Comment: `OS` decide according to their scale factor , need not to worry about that

Comment: If I got the width and height of the screen, how would I know if it requires 1x, 2x or 3x image?

Comment: `let fullScreenImageWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * UIScreen.main.scale`. Do the same for height.

Comment: I suggest reading this - particularly the section titled "Points Versus Pixels" - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW1

Comment: Yes I know how big the screen is, that is not the problem.... If I got the height and if got the width, how would I know what image it requires, depening on that height and width? How would I know: O yeah this is an 1000x1000 screen, this uses a @2x image?

Comment: You don’t, iOS decides that for you and hands you the right image.

Comment: @HAS So only Apple knows which devices uses 2x and 3x images?

Comment: No, you can find it out at runtime calling UIScreen.main.scale (or something along those lines), but you shouldn’t need to care :) The App Store delivers only those images to a device which it needs (so every retina device will only get the `@2x` images, every plus-sized iPhone only gets the `@3x` images and old non-retina devices get the `@1x` images. Edit: I just re-read you questions, sorry, yes in this case you should care :) )

Answer (score 24):

**@3x**:

- iPhone 11 Pro, Pro Max
- iPhone Xs, Xs Max
- iPhone X
- iPhone 8 Plus
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone 6s Plus
- iPhone 6 Plus

All other devices are **@2x**. (including the iPhone 11 and XR)

Link to [apple developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html) (New iPhones are still missing in the official documentation)

Comment: Yes I read this as well, but on some websites I see that some iPads use @ 3x, so I am confused.

Comment: And all iPads running iOS applications not designed for iPad use @1x, no matter what the device resolution.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm opening my iPhone app in iPad, which according to you should pick 1x asset, but it's not picking 1x, it's still picking 2x. I have made my 1x a smaller image but it's not picking it :( Any idea?

Comment: ipad pro is 3x I believe

Comment: Here's the updated link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html

Comment: [Relevant and useful visual resource](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)

Comment: @Shiva According to documentation, iPad uses 2x.

Answer (score 2):

Now there are different iPhone that uses @3x resolution images:

- iPhone X
- iPhone Xs
- iPhone Xs Max
- iPhone 8 Plus
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone 6s Plus
- iPhone 6 Plus

All other iPhone later iPhone 4s are uses @2x images.