# Xcode: image size at @1x is never been use

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcasset

Following the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049544/what-should-image-sizes-be-at-1x-2x-and-3x-in-xcode) I have created this 3 images

[image]
[image]
[image]

and I add the images to the assets:

[image]

The image should render @ 100x100:

`@1x -> 100 * 100`

`@2x -> 200 * 200`

`@3x -> 300 * 300`

But here is my question to you when is the @1x is been use becase I load the iPhone 4s in the simulator and is loading the @2x.

[image]

Can any of you knows when @1x image is been use?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: `@1x` images are only used on non-retina devices. The last iPhone to have a non-retina screen was the 3GS. However, the App Store icon that's 1024x1024 is technically a `@1x` since it doesn't require any other scale factors. You can get by without using `@1x` and I suspect Apple will get rid of it soon.

Comment: @slickdaddy "and I suspect Apple will get rid of it soon" Surely that would depend on issues of backward compatibility. At the moment you can still build backwards to iOS 8, which does run on some 1x devices. As long as you can do that, 1x is needed.

Answer (score 3):

The @1x is for iPad 2 and iPad mini and iPhones before the 4.

See the image for a detailed answer:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your app is native to iOS 12 and no earlier, the 1x image is *never* used as long as there is a 2x or 3x image. You app does not run on any 1x devices.

If your app has an earlier deployment target, e.g. iOS 11, then the 1x image is used on the iPad 2. iOS 12 does not run on the iPad 2, but iOS 11 does.

And so on. As your app is usable under earlier and earlier systems, more and more 1x devices come into play.