# How to determine best size of images in Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working in an iOS project and I need to use some local images so I added my images to image.xcassets and everything working apparently fine, the problem is that my images are in very heigh resolution and of course very heavy making my project and final size app heavier. The problem increases because those images are contained in CollectionViews and TableViews forcing the device to render more and use a lot memory.
And my doubt is: What's the best resolution for those images? or How to determine the best size?

Comment: may be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049544/what-should-image-sizes-be-at-1x-2x-and-3x-in-xcode?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/)

[image: About standard resolution]

For extra knowledge:

[image: Scale Factors]

Enjoy!