# how to remove flutter's default splash screen?

Tags: flutter

I'm a developer who is developing a flutter.

I have a question about the default splash screen of the flutter.

I found that the first time I created the flutter project, it basically included a splash screen with a flutter icon.

I looked it up to erase the default splash screen, but I got a reply that it is not possible in the flutter/dart stage.

To solve this problem, first of all, I wanted to customize the defalut splash screen using the flutter_native_splash library.

However, the library did not meet my requirements because it was impossible to insert elements other than images (ex. text).

So, I used the flutter_native_splash library to insert an icon with only pure white color to create a fake splash screen.

And I made a real splash screen, registered it as the initial screen of the GetX library, and set it up to move on to the next page after the schedule delay.

You can check the ones described above in the video below.

[image]

In this situation, I have two questions.

First, I wonder if I can insert text into the splash screen using the flutter_native_splash library.

Secondly, I wonder if there is a way to delete the default splash screen that is automatically generated by the flutter.

Answer (score 5):

The default splash screen cannot be overridden with Dart/Flutter alone. They are controls shown by the native Android/iOS context while the Flutter runtime is initializing. As such, any splash screen widget you create inside Flutter will show after the default splash screen. (Even if you completely remove the default splash image, the app would just be a blank while screen until Flutter finished loading, and that's bad design.)

There are instructions on how to change the default splash screen here :

**For Android**

Step 1: Go to android/app/src/main/res/drawable folder :
Here you will find a file launch_background.xml. This is where you can write some code and make it work.

Step 2: Open launch_background.xml

[image]

Step 3: Change Background

Uncomment line 7–11 and this is where you can change your background, maybe a color or image on line 4

```
<item android:drawable=”@color/ic_launcher_background” />
```

Step 4: Change Image/Icon

This is where (on line 10) you can change your app icon or to an image which will be in the center if android:gravity is center (Make sure you add your icons for different size devices for better result).

```
android:src=”@drawable/qart_trans”
```

And That’s it!! Woohoo

**For iOS**

Step 1: Open the project in iOS stuff in XCode

Step 2: Go to ios/Runner Folder

You will see here Assets.xcassets folder and LaunchScreen.storyboard. These are two things which we want.

Step 3: Open Assets.xcassets and click on LaunchImage

Paste your images/icons in 1x 2x 3x Options according to recommended sizes for devices

[image]

Step 4: Now Open LaunchScreen.storyboard

Click on the view and on the right panel click the down arrow like symbol change properties like background and content mode according to your need.

[image]

Step 5: Now Click the Image on the storyboard

Now on the right panel click the down arrow like symbol gain and change its properties as per need.

[image]

And That’s it again!! Voila!!!

Comment: I'd like to put text in, is there any way..?

Comment: add text in xml and you are done

Comment: according to this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html, there is no text type in drawable object. how do I put it...?

Comment: what sizes should the 1x 2x 3x LaunchImage be?

Comment: @LukePighetti for 1x, 2x, 3x sizes you can refer to this questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049544/what-should-image-sizes-be-at-1x-2x-and-3x-in-xcode